# How to use Ember's getters/setters on properties with dots?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my webapp, I have a model with properties whose names are dynamically generated based on data from the server. For example, I would normally reference this by doing something like this from my controller:

```
var str1 = 'property.name.with.dots'; // String from server
this.get('model.someProperty')[str1].integer = 2;
this.get('model.someProperty')[str1].integer += 1;
```

But Ember doesn't like this - it says I should use a `set` or `get` function. Which makes sense. So I want to do something like this in place of the last line above:

```
this.get('model.someProperty.' + str1).incrementProperty('integer');
```

This would work fine out of the box if `str1` didn't have dots. It does, though, so what can I do to get Ember's getters to work? I tried

```
this.get('model.someProperty')[str1].incrementProperty('integer');
```

but it doesn't work - the subobjects don't get Ember's methods by default.

Comment: I would suggest not using property names with dots; you're just going to create headaches for yourself. If you need to index using arbitrary strings, use a [Map](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Map.html).

Comment: I hadn't heard of Map before, I'll look into that - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely

Massage the data before handing it off to Ember, having dots in your name will just cause a plethora of chaining problems.

### Clean the data, I chose _ (this isn't deep cleaning, exercise for your fun)

```
App.cleanData = function(result){
  var response = {},
      re = new RegExp('\\.', 'g'),
      newKey;
  for(var key in result){
    newKey = key.replace(re, '_');

    response[newKey] = result[key];
  }
  return response;
};
```

### Use the cleaned data instead of the server data

```
App.FooRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return $.getJSON('/foo').then(function(result){
       return App.cleanData(result);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: While your method won't work exactly (the data is coming from Faye, not ajax), this is pretty much what I'm doing. Thanks for your help!